# java reflection field type before upcasting

Tags: java, reflection

I have a simple class

```
public class SomeService {

    private Number number = new Integer(0);
}
```

Is it possible to find out by means of java reflection the field type before upcasting?

I can just obtain Number type instead of Integer:

```
Field field = MealService.class.getDeclaredField("number");    
field.setAccessible(true);
System.out.println("impl:"+field.getType());
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

```
field.getType() returns the declared type.
```

If you want to know the instantiation type you have to first instantiate the field.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

    public class InstanceTypeInfo {
        private Number num = new Integer(0);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SecurityException,
            NoSuchFieldException, IllegalArgumentException,
            IllegalAccessException {
        InstanceTypeInfo dI = new InstanceTypeInfo();
        Field field = dI.getClass().getDeclaredField("num");
        System.out.println("Instance Type :" + field.get(dI).getClass());
        System.out.println("Decleration Type:" + field.getType());
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly logical : the information you get from the field type is the ***declared type***. If you want to get the actual type, you need to get the actual value of the field of the instance. Due to [polymorphism](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_polymorphism.htm) you cannot determine in advance the actual type of a value.

In your example, you can't change `number`'s value but it is rarely the case in real life.
For example :

```
public class SomeService {
    private Number number = new Integer(0);
    private void setNumber(Number number){
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

What if you do this?

```
SomeService service = new SomeService();
service.setNumber(new Double(0));//or more vicious : service.setNumber(0.0)
```

So, in order to get the type of the value, the most simple solution is to call `getClass` on the value or (especially if you want to upcast) use `instanceof`.
For example, if you absolutely want to use reflection :

```
Field field = SomeService.class.getDeclaredField("number");    
field.setAccessible(true);
Object value = field.get(service);
if(value instanceof Integer){
    Integer intValue = (Integer)value;
}
```